# counters/looping inside a SAS macro

Tags: loops, macros, sas, dataset

I am teaching a SAS course, and am dabbling a bit in simulations.  I am currently trying to simulate baseball lineups. I am not very strong at macros, and was able to do this code thru MUCH trial and error and some help previously on this site.  I was hoping somebody could help me to the finish line.

My goal here is to be able to work with counters correctly.
I am reading in a data set that has 9 observations, and has the variable called cutoff (it is the cutoff used according to the ability of the batter to determine a hit or not and will be compared to randvar).    The variable ‘order’ is there just to make it a little easier to follow (note that cutoff cycles back every 9 hitters).  Count_outs resets the outs to 0 once a third out is made (end of inning).

I need to be able to repeat reading in this 9 observation data set, and the way I have done it (with some help from here earlier) is to create a data set called ‘out’ that I have attached to my data set ‘orig’ in the way I have below.

Everything is working as I would like with a few exceptions.  I would like a counter that resets to 0 once 27 outs are made.

After 18 observations, it works as I would like it to, though the 19th observation, note the missings for the 19th observation.  So, of course, what I would like is for the 19th (and following) observations to have a random variable (it is missing every ninth observation starting with the 19th observation) as well as updating the counters accordingly.

the other issue which I think should be an easy fix is that count does not get off on the right foot.  note the first observation has a randvar = 0.18 (less than the cutoff, which should result in an out and have count=1.  however, it works correctly after that.  I have tried modifying this dozens of times). Can anybody help?

Thanks very much

```
%macro replicate(new,out,n)/des=’&out is &new repeated &n times.’;
  Data & out;
  Set &new;
  %do i=1 %to &n;
    Data &out;
      randvar=uniform(1);
      if randvar<cutoff then do;
        count+1;
        count_outs+1;
      end;
      set &out &new;
      if count_outs=3 then count_outs=0;
      if count=28 then do;
        set &new;
        count=1;
      end;
    run;
  run;
  %end;
%mend;
```

note:  I tried showing the output, but could not format it correctly.

Comment: It would have helped if you made your question a bit more generic. As baseball is not a 'thing' where I'm from, I know very little about it and therefore have a hard time understanding your question. Can you provide sample data and desired output? With that said, that code looks very strange. It looks like you put a data step inside a data step which doesn't make much sense. Also I will assume that your first `data & out;` statement was mistyped here and that you meant `data &out;`

Comment: thank you for response.  I did get an answer

Answer (score 1):

You're using macros in a way that is really not necessary or appropriate.  Macros just write SAS code - so don't put anything in a macro that's not legal to be written down normally, except if it has `%` before it.

Here you have a structure like:

```
data out;
  set in;
  data out; 
    set in out;
  run;
run;
```

That's obviously not going to work, right?  The outer data/set will just end quickly, and then the inner one will run.

In any event, you don't need to do any of this to do your simulation.  You can do everything outside of a macro.

```
data out;
  call streaminit(7);           *seed better random number engine;
  do pointvar = 1 by 1 until (outs=27);   *iterate starting at 1 and stop when 27 outs;
    randvar = rand('Uniform');  *better random number engine;
    if pointvar > 9 then pointvar=1;      *reset to 1 if over 9;
    set in point=pointvar;      *pull the row we need;
    if randvar < cutoff then do;
      outs+1;
      outs_inning+1;
    end;
    output;
    if outs_inning=3 then outs_inning=0;
  end;
  stop;
run;
```

This does what you want (more or less, you don't provide sample data so I can't test).  No macro required; you could certainly define any number of macro variables (for in, out, etc.) as you wish.

Comment: Agree. If you're teaching a SAS course, I would just teach SAS, not the macro language. After your students have learned a good bit of SAS, they can learn the macro language on their own, or in a second class.

Comment: hello Joe (and Quentin) thanks for response.  this is actually just something a few students wanted to look at (as did I), as we have discussed simulations in the ways of probabilities (p values, etc).    Joe, the nine numbers I have for cutoff are .74 , .73, .75, .70, .76, .78, .75, .72, .76.    I tried your code and it seemed to be hanging, so to speak.  let it run for 10 minutes or more.  something seems amiss. can you test here.  sorry, I am relatively new here.  is there a way to send files with numbers to make it easier for others if they would like to run them?  thanks again   John

Comment: @GKJohn Needs a `stop;` at the end, I omitted that.

Comment: Thanks again, Joe for response.  I have been playing around with this (to no avail) and trying to get it to repeat a game, so to speak, where it would start at the top of the lineup after 27 outs.  So for what I have right now, assume the 27th out is achieved with the 5th batter.  I would like to put this whole code inside of a loop where it starts the process again at the beginning of the data set (1sot observation, i.e, first batter).  So, assume I want to complete 3 iterations here.  3 games of 27 outs.  Is there a way to do this?  I tried doing the following.  (see following post)

Comment: %macro replicate(new,out,n)/des=’&new1 is &out repeated &n times
        Data &new;
        %do i=1 to &n;
        Set &out;
Output;
%end;

%mend;
%replicate(new,out,3);
Proc print;
The problem with this is that it is simply reading each observation 3 times.  So in the do i=1 to 3, followed by set out (three times it takes the first observation from out, then 3 times it takes the second observation from out, etc.   i.e.
Outs    randvar    cutoff   outs_inning
0 .84    .73     0
0 .84    .73     0
0 .84    .73     0
1 .61    .75     0
1 .61    .75     0
1 .61    .75     0 thx